Nslookup and tracert are blocked by group policy
On a domain-joined Windows 11 computer, the domain user gets "This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator" warning when he/she opens up cmd and tries to run nslookup or tracert commands. The user can run other commands like ping, or ipconfig on the same cmd session.
What would be the setting in a GPO to disable such commands?
Thanks.

It is probably AppLocker, check the logs in the Event Viewer:
Application and Services logs -> Microsoft - > Windows -> AppLocker
